# Merging Excel File in PHP using PHPSpreadSheet library

Tags: php, excel, merge, phpspreadsheet

I was trying to merge multiple excel files(around 2-10 files) using phpspreadsheet library. I got Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in merge.php on line 27. I've tried to check everything though. Is it perhaps, because of the format? But it is set to xlsx. And is it possible to merge xlsx and xls files at the same time?
This is my code block

```
<?php

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

   $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
   $inputFileNames = [
     'file1.xlsx',
     'file2.xlsx',
     'file3.xlsx'
   ];
   $sheetnames = [
     'Worksheet',
     'Worksheet1',
     'Worksheet2'
   ];
   $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
   $reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
   $inputFileName = array_shift($inputFileNames);
   $spreadsheetMain = $reader->load($inputFileName);
   $spreadsheetMain->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('page0');
   $num = 1;
   foreach ($inputFileNames as $book => $inputFileName) {
      echo ('$inputFileName: ' . $inputFileName) . '</br>';
      $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
      $clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet'.$num);
      $clonedWorksheet->setTitle('Worksheet'.$num);
      $spreadsheetMain->addExternalSheet($clonedWorksheet);
      $num++;
   }
   $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheetMain);
   $writer->save('prueba1.xlsx');
?>
```

[By the way this is the link for the code and files I tried to merge.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18NuIVtacLnT21dqRzkpOEkpGrPjcc5DE)

Any kind of help is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are cloning Spreadsheet to a variable.
First Create a Spreadsheet object and then clone.

`/** Create a new Spreadsheet Object **/
$clonedWorksheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();`